# Mocking specific expression in repository

Tags: c#, unit-testing, dependency-injection, repository, moq

I want to mock a specific expression in one of my repositories and I'm having some trouble.

I currently have:

```
Mock<Container> returnContainer = new Mock<Container>();
Mock<IRepository<Container>> CntnrRepository =
    new Mock<IRepository<Container>>();

CntnrRepository.Setup<Container>(repo => repo
    .Find(x => x.Name == "foo")
    .Returns(returnContainer.Object);
```

Whenever the following code runs it's returning null instead of my `Mock<Container>` above.

```
Container found = 
    containerRepository.Find(x => x.Name == cntnrName);
```

What am I doing wrong here?

### Edit

Below is the code that is using the injected repository:

```
public int Foo(Guid id, string name)
{
    Container found = 
        containerRepository.Find(x => x.Name == name);

    if (found != null)
        return CONTAINER_NOT_FREE;

    Container cntnrToAssociate =
        containerRepository.Find(x => x.Id == cntnrId);

    if (cntnrToAssociate == null)
        return CONTAINER_NOT_FOUND;

    return OK;
}
```

In the code above for one of my tests I need to return a value only in the first query (`Find`) to the `containerRepository`

Comment: What is the signature of the `IRepository<Container>.Find` method?

Comment: `IList<T> FindAll(Expression<Func<T, bool>> criteria);` where T is a Container

Answer (score 0, accepted):

### Workaround

I haven't found the solution I'm looking for as of now but I did find a decent workaround.  I ended up using Moq's `Callback` method to do what I want.  Please see the following:

```
int numCalls = 0;
List<Container> expectedContainers = new List<Container>();

//Add list of expected containers here.  Since I want the first call to return null
//and the 2nd call to return a valid container object I will fill the array with null
//in the 1st entry and a valid container in the 2nd
expectedContainers.Add(null);
expectedContainers.Add(new Container());

CntnrRepository.Setup<Container>(
                repo => repo.Find(It.IsAny<Expression<Func<Container, bool>>>()))
                .Returns(() => returnContainers[numCalls])
                .Callback(() => numCalls++);
```

The above code allows me to return different results at different times from the same repository.

So instead of looking for looking for specific linq expressions I return the correct objects based on the number of calls the function makes to the repository.

Answer (score 4):

**Edit: i updated the solution, this works with Expression-arguments**
**Edit2: i added a more general solution (look at the last test) which uses the ExpressionComparer from IQToolkit. That should satisfy any generic expression in a setup**

If you set it up as shown below you can return not null only for some input arguments

```
    [Test]
    public void SetupFunc_TestWithExpectedArgument_ReturnsNotNull()
    {
        // Arrange
        var repository = new Mock<IRepository<Container>>();
        repository.Setup(r => r.Find(It.Is<Expression<Func<Container, bool>>>(x => NameIsFoo(x)))).Returns(new Container());

        // Act
        Container container = repository.Object.Find(x => x.Name == "foo");

        // Assert
        Assert.That(container, Is.Not.Null);
    }

    [Test]
    public void SetupFunc_TestWithOtherargument_ReturnsNull()
    {
        // arrange
        var repository = new Mock<IRepository<Container>>();
        repository.Setup(r => r.Find(It.Is<Expression<Func<Container, bool>>>(x => NameIsFoo(x)))).Returns(new Container());

        // Act
        Container container = repository.Object.Find(x => x.Name == "bar");

        // Assert
        Assert.That(container, Is.Null);
    }

    private static bool NameIsFoo(Expression<Func<Container, bool>> expression)
    {
        if (expression == null)
            return false;

        var mExpr = expression.Body as BinaryExpression;

        if (mExpr == null)
            return false;

        var constantExpression = mExpr.Right as ConstantExpression;

        if (constantExpression == null)
            return false;

        return Equals(constantExpression.Value, "foo");
    }

    [Test]
    public void SetupFunc_TestWithExpectedArgumentUsingExpressionComparer_ReturnsNotNull()
    {
        // Arrange
        var repository = new Mock<IRepository<Container>>();

        Expression<Func<Container, bool>> expectedArgument = x => x.Name == "foo";

        repository.Setup(r => r.Find(It.Is<Expression<Func<Container, bool>>>(x => ExpressionComparer.AreEqual(x, expectedArgument)))).Returns(new Container());

        // Act
        Container container = repository.Object.Find(x => x.Name == "foo");

        // Assert
        Assert.That(container, Is.Not.Null);
    }
```

Comment: I get `cannot convert from 'System.Func<Entities.Container,bool>' to 'System.Linq.Expressions.Expression<System.Func<Entities.Container,bool>>'` when I try to compile that.

Comment: I compiled it and ran it, works. Which version of moq are you using?

Comment: Aha, I didn't see that your repository parameter was an Expression<Func>, mine is only Func<>. I'll look at it later

Comment: +1 Thanks for the help here Marius but this isn't quite the answer I was looking for.  I really appreciate your help on this.

Comment: My last take on this :-) I've added a test which shows you how you can use a comparer to setup any expression. You can probably wrap this up in a helper to ease the verbosity.

Answer (score 0):

Following seems to return non null object:

```
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        Mock<Container> returnContainer = new Mock<Container>();
        var CntnrRepository = new Mock<IRepository<Container>>();

        CntnrRepository.Setup<Container>(repo => repo.Find(x => x.Name == "foo")).Returns(returnContainer.Object);

        var found = CntnrRepository.Object.Find(x => x.Name == "foo");

        // Or if you want to pass the mock repository to a method
        var container = GetContainer(CntnrRepository.Object);
    }

    public static Container GetContainer(IRepository<Container> container)
    {
        return container.Find(x => x.Name == "foo");
    }
```

Instead of calling containerRepository.Find you have to call containerRepository.Object.Find. I wasn't even able to compile the code if I dropped the .Object part.

Edit: I added example how to pass the IRepository to a method

Comment: Does this work whenever you pass a string into the method `GetContainer` to put into the `Find` method?  `public static Container GetContainer(IRepository<Container> container, string name)`

Comment: I just tested this and it returns null whenever you are using a variable in the linq expression.

Answer (score 0):

It appears that the answer is "it can't be done."

See [Jason Punyon's answer to Moq.Mock - how to setup a method that takes an expression](https://stackoverflow.com/a/2751981/161457).

As per his answer, you can use

```
CntnrRepository.Setup(repo => repo.FindAll(
    It.IsAny<Expression<Func<Container, bool>>>()))
    .Returns(returnContainer.Object);
```

but you can't put any constraints on the expression. I suppose you could parse the expression using It.Is, but that's likely more trouble than it's worth for a mock.

This is one of several reasons why I am in the camp of "[don't expose IQueryable on repositories](http://www.weirdlover.com/2010/05/11/iqueryable-can-kill-your-dog-steal-your-wife-kill-your-will-to-live-etc/)." While you're only exposing IList, using Expression is going down the same slippery slope IMHO.

Comment: Well I found the following article that looked promising but I can't get it to work.  Apparently he got it to work but I didn't have much luck: http://www.codethinked.com/comparing-simple-lambda-expressions-with-moq

Comment: Nice article! You might try the link Jimmy Bogard posted in the comments - the ExpressionComparer of http://iqtoolkit.codeplex.com/

Comment: I did find a workaround for now.  I posted it as an answer above.  I will look into that code when I get a chance.  Thanks.