# Mocking a generic repository method

Tags: asp.net-mvc-3, linq, lambda, mocking, moq

for unit-testing my asp.net MVC web application, I'd like to mock my IGenericRepository (I'm using Moq).

The method that has to be mocked looks like this:

```
IEnumerable<TEntity> Get(Expression<Func<TEntity, bool>> filter = null, 
        Func<IQueryable<TEntity>, IOrderedQueryable<TEntity>> orderBy = null, string includeProperties = "");
```

I've already mocked the repository without any problems:

```
useraccountRepository = new Mock<IGenericRepository<Useraccount>>();
```

Now I'd like to tell Moq that when the Get method of my interface is called, a list of useraccounts should be returned:

```
useraccountRepository.Setup(r => r.Get(u => u.Email == useraccount.Email && u.Password == useraccount.Password)).Returns(useraccounts);
```

I think there is a mistake in my second lambda because this one works:

```
useraccountRepository.Setup(r => r.Get(null, null, "")).Returns(useraccounts);
```

But where's my error?

What also works:

```
useraccountRepository.Setup(r => r.Get(u => u.Email == useraccount.Email 
            && u.Password == useraccount.Password, null, "")).Returns(useraccounts);
```

It looks like the default parameter values don't apply in my mock. Why is that?

If I use

```
useraccountRepository.Setup(r => r.Get(u => u.Email == useraccount.Email 
            && u.Password == useraccount.Password, null, "")).Returns(useraccounts);
```

anyway, then the method in my controller throws an exception when the Get message is called:

```
private bool validateUser(Useraccount useraccount)
    {
        try
        {
            Useraccount useraccountLogin = UnitOfWork.UseraccountRepository.Get(
                u => u.Email == useraccount.Email && u.Password == useraccount.Password).Single<Useraccount>();

            return (useraccountLogin != null);
        }
        catch (Exception exc)
        {
            return false;
        }            
    }
```

Where are my mistakes?

Thank you in advance.
Michael

Comment: **What** doesn't work and **which** exception is thrown? You navigate around specifics like a pro...

Comment: Sorry for confusing you.

If inside my unit test the validateUser(...)-method is called (from inside a controller method) it throws an exception where UseraccountRepository.Get(...) is called:
[System.InvalidOperationException] = {"Sequence contains no elements"}.

"   at System.Linq.Enumerable.Single[TSource](IEnumerable`1 source)\r\n   at ...".

Answer (score 0, accepted):

According to this question [Moq.Mock<T> - how to setup a method that takes an expression](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2751935/moq-mockt-how-to-setup-a-method-that-takes-an-expression), setting constraints on expression parameters is unsupported by Moq.

Comment: What I've found and at least works is:

useraccountRepository.Setup(r => r.Get(It.IsAny<Expression<Func<Useraccount, bool>>>(), null, "")).Returns(useraccounts);

Is there a better way or is that already the best way for mocking the repository method I've shown?

Comment: I think it is your best bet. But obviously you have a problem when you need to mock two different calls with distinct expressions. I would consider scrapping the generic repo though. Many experts consider it an antipattern, partly due to poor testability.

Comment: Thank you for your help.
Your link took me to the right track. :)