# Mocking with anonymous parameter

Tags: c#, moq, ninject-mockingkernel

I am trying to Mock my repository layer and I have a method `GetSelection(Expression<Func<T, Boolean>> where)`.  I am using *Ninjects MickingKernel* with *Moq* to achieve this.

When I do the following, it is fine:

```
// Create instance of repository
var kernel = new MoqMockingKernel();
var templateRepoMock = kernel.GetMock<ITemplateRepo>();

// Setup mock
templateRepoMock.Setup(x=>x.GetSelection(y=>y.FieldName)
                .Returns(new List<Template>() {new Template { ... })); 
                // Lets pretend that FieldName is a bool!

// Call Service layer
var result = templateService.MyMethod();

// -> Service Layer method
public List<Template> MyMethod() 
{
    return _templateRepo.GetSelection(x=>x.FieldName);
}
```

But when I try and add an additional parameter within my expression I get an `ArgumentNullExeption`:

```
// Setup mock 
templateRepoMock.Setup(x=>x.GetSelection(y=>y.SomeOtherField.Id == 1 
                                         && y.FieldName)
                .Returns(new List<Template>() {new Template { ... }));
```

When I update my service to the following:

```
public List<Template> MyMethod(SomeObject myObject) 
{
    return _templateRepo.GetSelection(x=>x.SomeObject.Id == myObject.Id 
                                      && x.FieldName).ToList(); 
}
```

It appears to be fine if I update myObject.Id to 1.

Any ideas why this could be happening?

Comment: I have edited your title. Please see, "[Should questions include “tags” in their titles?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/19190/)", where the consensus is "no, they should not".

Comment: I always think very carefully about the content of my posts - alas I forgot to omit this.

Comment: I copied and ran your code but I didn't see any exception.  Where is the exception thrown?  Can you include more code that might be relevant? What version of Moq are you using? Also, if you haven't already, try to reproduce it yourself in a separate project; maybe you'll get the same results as me.

Comment: The exception is being thrown in the service layer - not within the test

Comment: Here are the versions I am using:   <package id="Moq" version="4.0.10827" targetFramework="net45" /><package id="Ninject" version="3.2.2.0" targetFramework="net45" />
  <package id="Ninject.MockingKernel" version="3.2.0.0" targetFramework="net45" />
  <package id="Ninject.MockingKernel.Moq" version="3.2.0.0" targetFramework="net45" />
  <package id="NUnit" version="2.6.3" targetFramework="net45" />

Comment: With your versions I still don't see an exception; you'll need to post a [SSCCE](http://sscce.org/) that reproduces it since I'm missing something that you have.  Also, if the error is thrown in your service layer, then can you not just debug the test and break where it's being thrown and see what is null?

Comment: Added more to the question to help explain my problem...

Comment: I have also added an example on GitHub https://github.com/mhooper/MockingKernel.Moq.Example

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I *still* don't see the exception that you do, even when using your Github project.  Instead, the test fails at the `VerifyAll` line with this message:

> Moq.MockVerificationException : The following setups were not matched:
>
> IProductRepository mock => mock.GetProducts(x => x.Name == "Test" && x.IsActive)

However, I think you may be chasing a red herring, as Moq doesn't support setting up methods that take an `Expression`.  See [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/2751981/1698557).

Comment: OMG that answered it.  Thank you for helping me with this!